# Change atom-text-editor pane scrollbar colours

Tags: html, css, atom-editor

I have just switched to atom from sublime text and tried to apply my usual themes. Unluckily the theme that I use ([spacegray eighties](https://atom.io/themes/spacegray-eighties-ui) sublime port) does not incorporate the correct theme for the scrollbars. I managed to fix the look of the scrollbars in the tree-view panel. However, I cannot apply the same to the atom-text-editor for some reason. My styles.less is the following:

```
atom-text-editor {
  // Apply same scrollbar color fix.
}

// Scrollbar color fix for SpaceGray
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background-color: #262626;

  &-track {}

  &-thumb {
    background-color: #404040;

    &:window-inactive {
      background-color: rgb(116, 115, 105);
    }
  }

  &-corner {
    background-color: #262626;
  }
}
```

And here a preview of my problem:

[image] [image]

I tried putting the same `::-webkit-scrollbar` CSS into the atom-text-editor with `!important` statements, but with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close, you have to wrap your styles inside `.scrollbars-visible-always`:

```
.scrollbars-visible-always {
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    background-color: #262626;    

    &-track {}    

    &-thumb {
      background-color: #404040;    

      &:window-inactive {
        background-color: rgb(116, 115, 105);
      }
    }    

    &-corner {
      background-color: #262626;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For some reason my Atom didn't update with these changes.  I put them in **base.less**.

Answer (score 4):

In Atom 1.18.0 the following works for me for all scrollbars:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 50px;
    height: 18px;

    &-track {
         border: 0px;
         border-radius: 0px;
         background-color: transparent !important;
     }

     &-thumb {
         background-color: rgba(213, 213, 213, 0.4) !important;
         border: 0px;
         border-radius: 0px;
     }
}

// for new opened files
.vertical-scrollbar {
    width: 50px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you answer came just in time ... this one works.

Comment: This didn't *exactly* work for me, but it gave me some important information. In particular, I needed to specify `.vertical-scrollbar` (as well as `.horizontal-scrollbar`) to ensure that the dimensions were *larger* than the webkit scrollbar dimensions. When they happened to be exactly equal to the webkit dimensions, the scrollbars would disappear whenever I switched tabs. At least for me, this really had nothing to do with "new opened files".

Answer (score 3):

Actually this does not seem to work anymore for current versions of Atom. With the following code I was able to style both the scrollbar in the tree view and in the editor windows:

```css
.tree-view-resizer, atom-text-editor::shadow  {
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    background-color: #262626;

    &-track {}

    &-thumb {
      background-color: #404040;

      &:window-inactive {
        background-color: rgb(116, 115, 105);
      }
    }

    &-corner {
      background-color: #262626;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it seems things have changed again as this doesn't work in 1.18.0