# Atom editor scrollbar size/color

Tags: atom-editor

I'm using Atom to develop in php but for me, but I have an issue with the editor, I use One Dark theme but I try to change the color and the size of right scrollbar of the opened file because is small and hard to see for me

I try this info
[Change atom-text-editor pane scrollbar colours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34225056/change-atom-text-editor-pane-scrollbar-colours)

But I don't see any changes.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**UPDATE:** The below answer applies to Atom < 1.13. Starting with Atom 1.13 the shadow dom was abondoned and the example should work as the original poster had put it (that is without the `::shadow` selector.

For Atom up to version 1.12:
Atom uses shadow DOM for the editor, that might be the reason it does not work for you. To style the scrollbar for both the editor and the tree view try this:

```css
.tree-view-resizer, atom-text-editor::shadow  {
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    background-color: #262626;

    &-track {}

    &-thumb {
      background-color: #404040;

      &:window-inactive {
        background-color: rgb(116, 115, 105);
      }
    }

    &-corner {
      background-color: #262626;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: the selector &-thumb works for change the color, 
Thanks

Comment: `atom-text-editor::shadow` is deprecated since version 1.13, use `atom-text-editor.editor`.

Comment: This [discussion at atom.io](https://discuss.atom.io/t/change-the-color-and-width-of-editors-sidebar/18545/12) has more solutions and explanations.

Answer (score 4):

1. Select "File" -> "Stylesheet...".
2. Add code to below and save.

```
.scrollbars-visible-always {
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 35px;
    height: 12px;
  }
}

 // has to be bigger than webkit-scrollbar
.vertical-scrollbar {
  width: 35px !important;
}

// has to be bigger than webkit-scrollbar
.horizontal-scrollbar {
  height: 30px !important;
}
```